# How to save the data of a html form in django

Tags: html, django

I have two html modals in a single page one for sign up and another for sign in. But i can't figure out a way to save that data in django database. I am new to django so i don't know how to relate a html file to django. I have linked it as a front page but as far as back end, i am totally lost. i need help from scratch. here is my html file. thanks in advance.

```html
<body>

<ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

<h1 style="color: white; text-align: center; padding: 260px 0px 0px 30px;">getTogether</h1>
<h3 style="color: white; text-align: center;">A place to socialize and make friends</h3>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" class="button button1">Sign Up</button>

<div id="id01" class="w3-modal w3-animate-opacity">
  <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">×</span>
  <form class="modal-content animate" action="/home/user_profile" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="container">
      <label><b>Name</b></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Name" name="email" required>

        <label><b>Email</b></label>
      <input type="email" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>

        <label><b>Contact Number</b></label>
      <input type="text" name="Phone Number" pattern="[7-9]{1}[0-9]{9}" placeholder="Enter Your Contact Number" name="email" required>

      <label><b>Password</b></label>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>

      <label><b>Repeat Password</b></label>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" name="psw-repeat" required>
      <input type="checkbox" checked="checked"> Remember me
      <p>By creating an account you agree to our <a href="#">Terms & Privacy</a>.</p>

      <div class="clearfix">
        <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
       <a href="{% url 'user_profileview' %}"><button type="submit" class="signupbtn">Sign Up</button></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('id01');

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='block'" class="button button1">Sign In</button>

<div id="id02" class="w3-modal w3-animate-opacity">
  <span onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">×</span>
  <form class="modal-content1 animate" action="/home/user_profile" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="container">
      <label><b>Name</b></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Name" name="email" required>

      <label><b>Password</b></label>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>

      <div class="clearfix">
        <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn1">Cancel</button>
        <a href="{% url 'user_profileview' %}"><button type="submit" class="signupbtn1">Sign In</button></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('id02');

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: hi, for signin you should have a url and for sign up you should another url for example => signin url is `/login` and signup url is `/signup`. find this two url in urls.py and use them in from action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As sugested, you need two handlers for each form.

1. In the template, change the url's of the forms, one `/login` and other `/signup` or whatever.
2. Change the `urls.py` accordingly, for example:

   ```
   urlpatterns = [
       url(r'^/signup$', views.signup, name='signup'),
       url(r'^/login$', views.login, name='login'),
       # some other views
   ]
   ```
3. in your `views.py`:

   ```
   from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
   from django.shortcuts import render

   def signup(request):
       if request.POST:  # needed if you use the same URL for GET and POST
           email = request.POST.get('email')
           name = request.POST.get('name')
           # and so on ...
           # create user, set up password, etc.
           user = User.objects.create_user(...)  # your user database model
           return render(request, 'yourapp/user_profile.html', {
               'user': user
           })

   def login(request):
       if request.POST:
           email = request.POST.get('email')
           password = request.POST.get('psw')
           # login user
           user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
           if user:
               return render(request, 'yourapp/user_profile.html', {
                   'user': user
               })
           else:
               # redirect to error page
   ```

This is a very simple setup, you will be better using Django's `Form` and class views. But it's OK if you are learning Django.

Finally, please note that in your template, you are using `<input name="email">` for multiple elements.

Please refer to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/) for a better understanding about the authentication system. You may want to read about [shortcuts](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/shortcuts/) as well.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am trying that after both, sign in and sign up, the user end up at the same page that is user's profile page, that's why i have given same urls.., i'll change them if you say it's wrong

Comment: I see, then in both cases you must redirect to the user's profile page. I'll update my answer.

Comment: And your approach of same url for login and register is not _wrong_, but is better to map one view to one url.

Comment: thanks for the help, but i need models.py as well right?, to save data, and can you please suggest me some source from where i can get some help other than documentation.

Comment: Then I suggest to go through the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial01/) to understand every detail.